# GCC assembly code shows 32bit registers on 64bit machine

Tags: c, x86-64, ptrace

I am trying to learn how to use ptrace library for tracing all system calls and their arguments. I am stuck in getting the arguments passed to system call.
I went through many online resources and SO questions and figured out that on 64 bit machine the arguments are stored in registers `rax(sys call number), rdi, rsi, rdx, r10, r8, r9`
in the same order. Check [this website](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Interfacing_with_Linux) .

Just to confirm this I wrote a simple C program as follows

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
int main() {
  printf("some print data");
  open("/tmp/sprintf.c", O_RDWR);
}
```

and generated assembly code for this using `gcc -S t.c` but assembly code generated is as below

```
    .file   "t.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "some print data"
.LC1:
    .string "/tmp/sprintf.c"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    $2, %esi
    movl    $.LC1, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    open
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

As you can see this code is storing parameters on `esi` and `edi` instead. 
Why is happening?

Also please guide me on what is the best way to access these passed arguments from these registers/memory location from a C code? How can I figure out if the contents of register is the argument itself or is it a memory location where actual argument is stored?

Thanks!

Comment: On an x86 64-bit processors if you change the contents of a 32-bit register the **zero extended** result is placed into the entire 64-bit register. Using the 32-bit registers can shorten the encoding of the instructions. _EDI_ is the lower 32-bits of the register _RDI_ and _ESI_ is the lower 32-bits of _RSI_

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I am trying to access these registers from ptrace call. So from your comment even if I try to access rdi it should give me correct data, am I correct?

Comment: If you place a vale in a 32-bit register it should be the same value as the 64-bit register but be 64-bits wide. So looking at the 64-bit register is correct. So although _EDI_ was written to, the contents are viewable through the 64-bit register _RDI_ .

Comment: Thanks! In case of string how are the values stored? are they directly stored in a register or does registe point to a memory location where actual value is?

Comment: Assuming you are using AT&T syntax which you are in this case - If you see a label with a `$` sign in front of it like `$.LC0` that tells the assembler to use the value of the label (which is its address) not what is stored at that address. You generally pass the pointer to a string. `movl    $.LC0, %edi` moves the **address** of the string "some print data" into _EDI_.

Comment: So if first argument to open call is stored in rdi, then the contents of rdi is actually the memory location where string '/tmp/sprintf.c' is stored?

Comment: Also one more thing I can't see any int 80 call in the assembly code? Why is that?

Comment: Your code is using the _C_ library (glibc on Linux). `printf` is the _C_ function that displays your text. Under the hood the `printf` function is doing the low level call on your behalf. Same thing for `open`. When you use `-S` to get the assembly output it will not show you the assembler code for the _C_ library functions. On a side note: On 64-but Linux it is preferred you use `syscall` rather than `int 0x80`.

Comment: [Ryan Chapman's blog](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64) is a good source of the Linux 64-bit system calls and their parameters.

Comment: `int 80` will segfault, IIRC.  `int 0x80` calls the 32-bit ABI.  `syscall` calls the 64-bit ABI.  See [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info); there seems to be a lot of stuff you don't know, but that's explained by links in the tag wiki.

Answer (score 0):

> this code is storing parameters on `esi` and `edi`

32-bit instructions are smaller, thus preferred when possible.  See also [Why do most x64 instructions zero the upper part of a 32 bit register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register).

---

> How can I figure out if the contents of register is the argument itself or is it a memory location where actual argument is stored?

The AMD64 SystemV calling convention never implicitly replaces a function arg with a hidden pointer.  Integer / pointer args in the C prototype always go in the arg-passing registers directly.

structs / unions passed by value go in one or more registers, or on the stack.

The full details are documented in [the ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-r252.pdf).  See more links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.  http://www.x86-64.org/documentation.html is down right now, so I linked the current revision on github.

Comment: @CL.: thanks for the doc-links cleanups in my answers, especially taking care to replace the links with a similar Wikipedia link when appropriate :)